# MS-Access 2013 web app upload on SharePoint

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

> I want to know if i must upload my access 2013 web app only on office 365 SharePoint or can i upload it on another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create Access 2013 web apps, you need to have everything in one of these two options:

1. A subscription to Office 365 that includes Access Services. Most of the Office 365 plans include Access Services but there might be a few that don't. You'll also need Access 2013 client.
2. Your own server with SharePoint 2013, the Access Services piece with it (I think the Enterprise license levels include it), and SQL Server 2012 or higher. You'll also need Access 2013 client. If you are in an organization and they have all of those pieces in place, then you should be Ok with creating, editing, and using Access 2013 web apps provided of course your administrators have set up and turned on all of the services properly and you've been given the appropriate permissions.

Naturally, working with Office 365 is a lot easier since all of the setup work is done for you if an on-premise setup is not an option within your organization.

You cannot take an Access 2013 web app package and install it on another type of generic web server if that's what you're asking. You have to have the pieces in place mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i buy sharepoint online plan 1(http://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans), i will have office 365 only with sharepoint or only sharepoint??? And it says that included access services, so i could have a web access app, right?

Comment: Hi Dimicious. SharePoint Online is different than Office 365. If it helps, think of Office 365 as a suite of services that has a whole bunch of available services. SharePoint Online would a subset of that. You wouldn't have as many potential bells and whistles with SharePoint Online as you would with Office 365 plans. However, for your specific needs, you might not need all the extra services and products that Office 365 provides.
To answer your question, yes if you purchase one of those SharePoint Online plans you should be able to use Access 2013 web apps. You'll still need Access 2013 too.